# usable vs installed RAM - how to expand

Tags: memory, ramdisk

I have two questions on RAM, because I saw there is difference between usable and installed memory:

1. Right now I have 4GB RAM (2 + 2) installed but task manager shows I have 5.9GB, how is this possible?
2. I would like to upgrade memory to at least 8GB or 16B buying a new one. Are there some requisites that I should respect (also with regards to usable/installed RAM)? For example I have 2 slots, can I install in one slot 8GB and in the second keep the current one (2GB) for a total of 10GB?

Thank you.

EDIT: Attaching CPU-Z screenshot

[[image: CPU]

[[image: SPD]

[[image: SPD2]

Comment: Can you run CPU-Z and post the results of the CPU and SPD tab? It will let you know the actual RAM type and size in each slot.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, Tjank you for your answer. I edited my post with the 2 screenshots.

Comment: Check the SPD tab, default is Slot 1. Check all slots to verify no. of RAM sticks

Comment: ok, I attached also the 3rd slot (2nd and 4th are empty). This means that  in a slot I have a stick of 4GB ram and in the 2nd slot I have 2GB, is this the reason why I have 6GB?

Comment: Yes. Thats why 6GB

Comment: Normally it is suggested to put RAMs in pairs i.e. if you look at the RAM slots mostly RAM Slot 1 and 3 will have same color and so will 2 & 4. This is because processor can access data from both RAMs simultaneously if both RAM are of same size. If that is the case with your mother board too then buy a 2 GB and 4 GB RAM and put them as per the color coding i.e. 2 GB in 1 & 3 and 4 GB in 2 & 4. Let me know if the color coding exists on your mother board.

Comment: I think I have just 2 slots not 4...I do not know actually why CPU-Z shows 4 in the dropdown menu. I'll check again better but I am pretty sure.

Comment: I have an Asus A55VD

Comment: This is a laptop. Then you are correct. This may only have two slots. You can buy a 4 GB RAM and replace the 2 GB one to get total 8 GB. Or buy two 8 GBs and replace 2 & 4. The only limit is money.